# Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $a$, $a>0$. Then

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $a$, $a>0$. Then

A.$\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n $ converges but $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} $ diverges

B.$\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n $ diverges but $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n} $ converges

C.Both $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n $ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n} $ converge

D.Both $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n $ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n} $ diverge

I am trying to solve by counter examples, but i could not think of.
Thanks

**EDIT**

If i take sequence to be $a +\frac{1}{n}$. Then series $\frac{a_n}{n}$= $\frac{a}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}$.Using comparison test with 1/n, it diverges. So i have to choose now between A and D

Comment: The first series can't converge (that requires $a=0$). The terms in the second series are at least as large as $a/n$, so that series diverges as well (harmonic series diverges). So neither series can converge.

Comment: Correction: I guess the terms of the second series only need to be *asymptotically* close to $a/n$ but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have the diverge.  Since $a_n \to a > 0$, there exists an $N$ so that for all $n \geq N, a_n > \frac{a}{2}$.  Then we have $$ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^{N-1} a_n +\sum\limits_{n= N}^\infty a_n > \sum\limits_{n= 1}^{N-1} a_n+ \sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty \frac{a}{2} = \infty $$
and 
$$ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^{N-1}\frac{a_n}{n} +\sum\limits_{n= N}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} > \sum\limits_{n= 1}^{N-1} \frac{a_n}{n}+ \sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty \frac{a}{2n} = \infty  $$
where the latter sum diverges since it is a rescaling of the tail of the harmonic series.

Comment: please suggest counter example for A

Comment: This proves that literally *any* sequence converging to a positive real number will be a counterexample to A.  Surely you can come up with a sequence converging to a positive number.

Comment: {1 - 1/2^i} --> 1 is a counter example.  .9, .99, .999, .... is a counter example.  3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141 --> \pi is a counter example.

Comment: The easiest counter example is {$a_n = 1$}.  $a_n \rightarrow 1$ and $\sum a_i = \sum 1$ and $\sum a_i/i = \sum 1/i$ both diverge.

Answer (score 1):

You should develop your math intuition. $a_n \rightarrow a$ means eventually the $a_n$ are very close to $a$ so $\sum a_n$ is gets close to $\sum a$ which obviously diverges.  And so $\sum a_n/n$ gets close to $\sum a/n$ ~ $a\sum 1/n$ which is the harmonic series which diverges.

But that's not math.  That's just intuition.

$a_n \rightarrow a$ means for any $a/2 > \epsilon > 0$ the is an $N$ so that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.  So $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i - \sum_{i=0}^n a_i = \sum_i={n + 1}^{\infty} a_i > a_n > a - \epsilon > \epsilon $.  So there is *no* $N$ such that $|\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i - \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$.   So the sum diverges.

Now note $\sum_{i = N+1}^{\infty}a_i/i < \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}(a + \epsilon)/i = (a + \epsilon)\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} 1/i$ which diverges as it is the harmonic series.

So both diverge.

So D.